# CustomEvent returns value when children mousemoved

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to archive this, when the mouse of child is moved:

```
document.querySelector("element").addEventListener("oncolorchange", (e) => {
    console.log(e.getColor());
});
```

e.getColor() should give a value, which is defined in the javascript class.
I currently have this:

```
const event = new CustomEvent("oncolorchange", {
     detail: {
          color: this.getColor()
     }
});

this.#element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you create `CustomEvent` object you can modify it's properties.

```
const event = new CustomEvent("oncolorchange");
event.getColor = function() {...};

this.#element.dispatchEvent(event);
```